# The Kivy APK mobile application fails to launch even after a successful conversion by Buildozer

Tags: android, python-3.x, kivy, apk, buildozer

While developing a mobile application with Kivy, I encountered an issue where the APK doesn't launch on the mobile phone after successful conversion using Buildozer. The application opens and closes immediately. Although there are no errors when running the application on PyCharm, troubleshooting the problem by repeatedly converting the program into an APK file and testing it is time-consuming, as the conversion process takes approximately half an hour each time. I'm seeking a faster way to identify and troubleshoot the problem without going through the entire APK conversion process for each iteration.

Despite my attempts at debugging and utilizing adb logcat, no specific errors are being generated that can be addressed. As a temporary solution, I'm resorting to deleting portions of the code and converting it into an APK file to identify the issue causing the application not to launch. However, this approach is extremely time-consuming

Answer (score 1):

Although I couldn't discover a quicker method for compiling the program into an APK, I managed to identify and resolve the issue I was facing.

First I had the following error on cython:
[image]

I fixed the Cython error by installing Cython 0.29.21:
[image]

While the error vanished, the issue of the APK not opening on the phone continued to persist. To address this, I resolved the problem by installing the most recent version of Cython (0.29.35), resulting in the successful resolution of the issue.
[image]